# In Yakuza Dead Souls, what plates can I sell?

Tags: yakuza-dead-souls

It appears the silver plate is used during modding, but is it safe to sell the gold and platinum plates, or are they also used for some mod(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [challenge database on PS3Trophies.org](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/yakuza-end-dead-souls/152256-challenges-database.html), you need the following plates for mods:

- 5 bronze
- 2 silver
- 4 gold
- 5 platinum